# Get dates of a month with specific day numbers of week in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have set of day no like [1,2,3..7] corresponding to [Sunday,Monday,Tuesday...Saturday]

and user A preferred day like [1,3,5] from above Set.

I have an event of 5 days. Starting and ending date of event depends on User's preferred days. For Users A this event will be only on 1st,3rd,and 5th day of a week as this is User A's preference.

User will just select his event start date from any of his preferred days and other event dates should be distributed automatically as per his selected day numbers.
Suppose User A selected 3/2/2013(MM/dd/yyyy) as his event start date then other event dates will be:

```
* Event day 1 ->3/2/2014(startDate)
* Event day 2 ->3/4/2014
* Event day 3 ->3/6/2014
* Event day 4 ->3/9/2014
* Event day 5 ->3/11/2014(End Date)
```

i have to get only these dates by skipping other dates and need to save these dates in Db.
Preferred days will be different for each user and start date may be any day from their preferred days.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Please post this as an answer to this question, instead of answering it in your own question.

Comment: I have edited my question. I'll post my answer in answer section. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly but if you try to find the next instance of a date that meet the requirement of being day 1,3,5 of the week I would advise you to build a list of the next dates running (after the database). A list of the user preferred day of week. Then find the first date that is running on one of the preferred days.

```
List<DateTime> nextDates = //find the next dates in database
List<DayOfWeek> preferedDays = //user preferred days after database
DateTime date = nextDates.FirstOrDefault(d => preferredDays.Contains(d.DayOfWeek))
```

Let me know if you have trouble understanding my proposition or if I'm not answering your problem at all :)

Cheers

Edit: code more explicit